# Is velocity of a fluid the gradient of something physically significant?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vector-fields

For incompressible flow,
$$\nabla\cdot \mathbf v=0.$$
That means $\mathbf v$ got to be the gradient of some scalar field.

How can I find the scalar field? Is it physically important?

Comment: It's called the velocity potential. And, well, it's important because its gradient is the velocity.

Comment: Why does the divergence of v being equal to zero automatically imply the the velocity is the gradient of some scalar field?

Comment: The condition for $\vec{v}$ to be the gradient of a function $\phi$ is that $\nabla \times \vec{v}=\vec{0}$ not $\nabla\cdot\vec{v}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the flow is potential, then we have $\vec {u}=\nabla \phi$ and $\nabla .\vec {u}=\nabla ^2\phi=0$. Then the equations of motion are reduced to the Bernoulli integral.The Laplace equation $\nabla ^2\phi=0$ with boundary conditions is widely used in aerodynamics to calculate the distribution of velocity and pressure in flows with a small Mach number. Figure 1 shows the velocity distribution in a potential incompressible flow (left) and in a viscous compressible flow with Mach number $M= 0.25$ (right) for the [NACA 2415](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=n2415-il) airfoil with the angle of attack $\pi /16$. 
[image: fig1]